# Converting set of integers to a bitarray for memory-efficient lookup

Tags: python, int, bitarray

I have a set of 150M integers in Python that I'd like to use for filtering data. Each of these integers is a "user ID" stored in a 32-bit format and I want to remove any users that are in the set. The set is too big as I need to transfer it to lots of workers on a cluster, where each worker has a limited amount of memory. Seeing as I only need a binary value (user is set / not in set) it seems feasible to do this using a bitarray.

The IDs start at 0 and finish at roughly 300M (i.e. half the users are in the set). The entire bitarray should be set to False (i.e. 0) except for the locations that are contained in the set of ints.

I've looked at [the `bitstring` package](https://github.com/scott-griffiths/bitstring) and [the `bitarray` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/), but I'm not sure which is better for my purpose and how I should go about it. Can anyone provide some guidance or a small example of how to convert my set to a bitarray and then do a lookup using it?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use a Bloom Filter? This sounds like the exact use case for them.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer `bitarray` and assuming you have such a set (only larger):

```
# Just some random set
myset = {5, 27, 142, 824}
```

Then you could use `bitarray` to create a `bitarray` (of appropriate length) containing only `False`:

```
from bitarray import bitarray
ba = bitarray(1000)  # length 1000
ba.setall(False)     # contains only zeros
```

However there's no native support for creating one from a `set`, so you'll need a loop to set the appropriate values:

```
for item in myset:
    ba[item] = True
```

And you could check if the value by indexing:

```
print(ba[5])   # True
print(ba[6])   # False
print(ba[27])  # True
```